# crop screen maximized resolution

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex4.5

i would like to create some Flex Desktop Application that will be always in front of other applications (appWindow.alwaysInFront = true). It should looks like tiny bar at the top of the screen (eg. width = screenWidth, height = 50px). I know how to do that. But I have problem with other applications - when i maximize them, they are under my application. Is there any way how to say to the system, that maximized resolution for other apps is other than default?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your question is unclear... you're setting the application to always appear in front of all other windows... and then asking to NOT have the application appear in front of other windows?

Comment: I'm asking to have other applications under my app. Take a look on this img:

Comment: I'm asking to have other applications under my app. Take a look on this img: [link](http://upload.emte.cz/flex-app-bounds.png)...is it clear now?

Comment: You should intercept the maximize message (event) for the whole system and resize the interested window properly. Don't do it. I get very annoyed by programs that take control of MY desktop, stealing space.

Comment: yea, but my app is developed for targeted persons only and they needs it. Can you, please, tell me, how to do that in Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with flash code, because you're interfering with external applications. At best, you could write some native code in another language and use AIR to execute that code but I can't really see that working out well, or at least being anything less than a massive undertaking.

If you do want to attempt this however, you can find some info about executing native code from AIR here: [How can i on button press execute a command in the command prompt and get back the output in ActionScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143606/how-can-i-on-button-press-execute-a-command-in-the-command-prompt-and-get-back-t/6143992#6143992)